# Google Cloud Storage Signed URL Upload + Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, dropzone.js

I'm trying to use Dropzone.js to upload directly to Google Cloud Storage using a Signed URL. I've managed to override the upload URL for each file added to Dropzone. Chrome dev tools says a `PUT` request is occurring but I inevitably receive a HTTP 400 error in response.

Here's my Dropzone.js config

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    url: '/',
    uploadMultiple: false,
    method: 'PUT',
    parallelUploads: 1,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    header: '',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    autoDiscover: false,
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*,video/*',
    accept: function(file, done) {
        var self = this;
        $.post('/api/v1/signed_file_upload', {key: window.apiKey, name: file.name, type: file.type}, function(data) {
            if(data.success) {
                file.uploadURL = data.data;
                done()
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.processFile(file)
                }, 0)
            } else {
                done(data.message)
            }
        })
    },
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.on('processing', function(file) {
            self.options.url = file.uploadURL
        })

        this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
            var _send = xhr.send
            xhr.send = function() {
                _send.call(xhr, file)
            }
        });

    }
};
```

My signed URL has the following structure:

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{bucket_name}/o/{object_name}.png?GoogleAccessId=xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1521610072&Signature=xxx`

Chrome Dev Tools shows this for the upload request:

[image]

I inevitably receive an HTTP 400 response. Sometimes the body is empty and sometimes it returns a JSON object saying

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badContent",
                "message": "Unsupported content with type: image/jpeg"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Unsupported content with type: image/jpeg"
    }
}
```

My signature generating function is

```
function storage_url($file_name, $bucket_name = '', $content_type = '', $method = 'PUT', $duration = 3000) { 
    $expires      = time() + $duration; 
    $signature    = '';
    $to_sign      = ($method . "\n\n" . $content_type . "\n" . $expires . "\n" . '/' . $bucket_name . '/' . $file_name); 
    $private_key  = json_decode(file_get_contents('xxx.json'))->private_key;

    if(!openssl_sign( $to_sign, $signature, $private_key, 'sha256' )) 
    { 
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature)); 
    }

    error_log($to_sign);

    return 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/' . $bucket_name . '/o/' . urlencode($file_name) . 
        '?GoogleAccessId=' . 'xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com' . 
        '&Expires=' . $expires . 
        '&Signature=' . $signature;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lee , are you able to upload the files to GCS ? I am working on it , but getting some issue . Here is the problem I am facing . Could you please check in your free time and help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325196/why-i-can-not-upload-more-than-2-mb-file-to-gcs?noredirect=1#comment93575736_53325196

Comment: Could you please share your dropzone code that is working ..? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCS has two APIs. The first, the XML API, uses domains like `storage.googleapis.com`. The second, the JSON API, uses domains like `www.googleapis.com`.

You're using the JSON API, which is fine, but unfortunately it doesn't support signed URLs. Craft an upload URL using the XML API's format: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload