# Dropzone.js - resize image before uploading to Google Cloud Storage using signed url?

Tags: dropzone.js, resize-image

Is it possible to use the resize capability of Dropzone.js when uploading to Google Cloud Storage by using signed URLs?

I am able to upload an image to GCS by following the instructions here: [Google Cloud Storage Signed URL Upload + Dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398399/google-cloud-storage-signed-url-upload-dropzone-js).

The problem is, since the upload has to be hijacked, the image transformation done by Dropzone.js is lost, beacause it apparently does not affect the file object I (xhr.)send. Is there a way to overcome this behaviour?

Comment: This issue doesn't seem to be related to google-cloud-storage, as all the action is [not] happening in Dropzone.js library. I would also recommend you to paste here your code so that people can see directly what is happening.

Comment: An option I can think of is to use the `dataUrl` that dropzone generates on the `thumbnail` event to generate a new file with the resized image, and then replace the original file with this new resized file.