# Upload Image from Google Cloud Function to Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, busboy

I'm attempting to handle file uploads using a Google Cloud Function. This function uses Busboy to parse the multipart form data and then upload to Google Cloud Storage.

I keep receiving the same error: `ERROR: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/xxx.png'` error when triggering the function.

The error seems to occur within the `finish` callback function when storage.bucket.upload(file) attempts to open the file path `/tmp/xxx.png`.

Note that I can't generate a signed upload URL as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396849/google-cloud-functions-upload-to-google-cloud-storage-via-http) since the application invoking this is an external, non-user application. I also can't upload directly to GCS since I'll be needing to make custom filenames based on some request metadata. Should I just be using Google App Engine instead?

Function code:

```
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const _ = require('lodash');

const projectId = 'xxx';
const bucketName = 'xxx';


const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
});

exports.uploadFile = (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        const uploads = []
        const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();

        busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename)
            var obj = {
                path: filepath, 
                name: filename
            }
            uploads.push(obj);

            var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(obj.path);
            file.pipe(writeStream);
        });

        busboy.on('finish', () => {
            _.forEach(uploads, function(file) {

                storage
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .upload(file.path, {name: file.name})
                .then(() => {
                  console.log(`${file.name} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.error('ERROR:', err);
                });


                fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
            })

            res.end()
        });

        busboy.end(req.rawBody);
    } else {
        res.status(405).end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually gave up on using Busboy. The latest versions of Google Cloud Functions support both Python and Node 8. In node 8, I just put everything into async/await functions and it works fine.

Comment: Hello @swigganicks  I am also facing same issue if you got it fixed, can you please explain in details or post some example code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @swigganicks, would appreciate a sample as facing the same

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the code for it anymore. I ended up using Python instead.